# How do I let only specific PCs connect to via SSH?

Tags: networking, server, security, ssl, certificates

I have an Ubuntu Server and I want only a few PCs to be able to connect to my server via SSH (on port 22). Is there a way that I can create an certificate that I would install on the few PCs that are allowed on the server?

Comment: Do you mean ssh? If so, look up private key authentication.

Comment: As an extra level of security you could allow only specific IPs to access ssh. For instance: `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24  to any port 22` to allow a subnet, or `sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any port 22` to allow a specific IP. You can repeat this for all IPs to allow, and then `sudo ufw enable`. Keep in mind you would need open any other services you provide in ufw as well: `sudo ufw allow http` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh key-based authentication.

1. Generate private and public ssh key  on one of PC using,

   ssh-keygen
2. Configure your ubuntu server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

   `PubkeyAuthentication yes`
   `PasswordAuthentication no`
3. restart sshd service on ubuntu server

   `systemctl restart sshd.service`
4. Add genetated public key into ubuntu servers
   /home/users-home/.ssh/authorized_keys
5. Place generated private key in /home/users-home/.ssh/ path on each
   PC.

Comment: the pcs i want to give the permissions to are windows machines. where to i have to put it there?

Comment: you can use putty tool.. put the private key where you prefer.